# Cannot change audio output for Chromium or Firefox

Tags: sound

I can change my audio output to my headphones in the audio settings, and it changes for every program except for Chromium and Firefox.  No matter what I change my audio output to, Chromium and Firefox still use my speakers, which I do not want to use, I want to use my headset.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you change the audio output settings to headphones before or after launching Firefox/Chromium ? If you change the audio settings after launching Firefox/Chromium, I guess you should try changing the audio output to headphones before launching Firefox/Chromium in order to use your headphones instead of speakers.